# Detect Android App Is Running In Debug Mode

Tags: android, linux, security

Without recompiling the app, user are able to make the app debuggable using xposed to debug/heapdump the app

Is there any method (root or non root) to detect the app is currently:

- Running in debug mode

or

- The app is started using debuggable flag in zygote

or

- App is being heap dumped

> Using `BuildConfig.DEBUG` and `ApplicationInfo`, and check the flags
>   field for `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` **doesn't works** since the app started by zygote with debug flag directly

Below is the code that hook the process class

```
    try {
        Method start = Process.class.getMethod(
                "start", String.class, String.class, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, int[].class,
                Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class, String[].class);
        XposedBridge.log("start hook, appInfo: " + loadPackageParam.appInfo);
        XposedBridge.hookMethod(start, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam methodHookParam) throws Throwable {
                    int id = 5;
                    int flags = (Integer) methodHookParam.args[id];
                    if ((flags & 0x1) == 0) {
                        flags |= 0x1;
                    }
                    methodHookParam.args[id] = flags;
                    }
            }
        });
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: all apps is debuggable]

Comment: What Xposed module makes the app debuggable?

Comment: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.jecelyin.buildprop

Comment: Why do you say `BuildConfig.DEBUG` doesn't work? I use this to check for debug state, regardless of how the app was installed or started.

Comment: the module modify "Process.class" directly and start the app in debug mode, regardless your hardcoded BuildConfig values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a device with Xposed installed you can't prevent anything or rely on any data your app processes within the Java/dex code. Anything can be modified by Xposed.

Therefore the only way is to harden your app by adding native code that prevents execution on devices with Xposed installed. Good hardening frameworks also makes it really hard/nearly impossible to attach debuggers.

Answer (score 9):

> boolean **isConnected** = new Debug().isDebuggerConnected();

Determine if a debugger is currently attached.
[Documentation of Debug class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html)

Comment: I really don't know why this isn't the best answer. its simple and the only workaround I find that lets me be lazy as a developer. +1

Comment: Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'Debug'

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it is not possible to retrieve that information without root.

However, you can check if a debugger is connected. See [`Debug.isDebuggerConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#isDebuggerConnected())

Comment: That value will only return true when debugger is attached, user still able to do heap dump. Root method are welcomed too

Comment: Root: Create your own xposed module and hook the method with a low priority. I'm not experienced with linux shell, but that might be able to get the information too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` and on the `ApplicationInfo` which are now unreliable because of the exposed module.
You could create a global constant in your code.

```
public class DebugMode{
    public static final boolean ENABLED = true;
}
```

In your release version you set this to true, and in your debug version to false. You could also use [different source sets for buildflavours](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) for this. So you don't have to change them manually.

If `DebugMode.ENABLED` is true, you know your app is in Debug mode, else it is in release mode. If `DebugMode.ENABLED` is false, and `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is true, you know someone is tampering with the debug flag. If you know this, you could close your app, or take other actions to prevent a heap dump.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the xposed module is hooking `Process.class` not the `BuildConfig` nor `ApplicationInfo`